sql question for grouping asked in Accenture interview
I have a table with a column colA with values 43,7,23,8,19,55
I need the output as
colA  group
7     1
8     1
19    2
23    2
43    3
55    3

show me some light to achieve this with SQL function. TIA
this should be achieved with one DML statement.

Please update your question with the logic for defining the groups

Use ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY colA) toassign a unique sequential integer to each row, ordered by colA.
Then divide this row number by 2.0 (to ensure floating-point division) and then apply CEIL() to the result groups every two numbers into the same group by rounding up to the nearest whole number.
SELECT
  colA,
  CEIL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY colA) / 2.0) AS "group"
FROM
  your_table_name;


(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY colA) - 1) / 2 + 1 works with integer division.
